# arcpy.QuickExport_interop crashing python when exporting to gml

Tags: arcpy, export, arcgis-10.4, gml

arcpy.QuickExport_interop is crashing python when exporting to a gml.  We are running ArcGIS 10.4.1 on a Windows Server 2012 R2.  The same script runs successfully on two different desktops.

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: python.exe
  Application Version:  0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    5560ae54
  Fault Module Name:    arcgisscripting.pyd
  Fault Module Version: 10.4.0.5524
  Fault Module Timestamp:   567b1378
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 000000000008c1b0
  OS Version:   6.3.9600.2.0.0.272.7
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 6fd2
  Additional Information 2: 6fd24e2e58701489213ba4c83af23142
  Additional Information 3: 652c
  Additional Information 4: 652c12f5220101ef60f75474ab1ca3b6

Comment: Does QuickExport work in the Tool gui? If so, you might look at the Result window for the Python script parameters to verify tool usage.

Comment: Thank you.  The Quick Export tool does work as long as background processing is disabled.  If it is not, the result is an error message "001143 : Background server threw an exception".